# How can I change the preference for what program opens a type of link in OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, file-association, system-preferences

I recently upgraded Thunderbird to version 5, and I installed the plugin that allows the calendar tab to read/update webcal calendars.

Previous to the update, I had a Basecamp milestone calendar, a few Google calendars, and my Facebook event calendar plugged into Thunderbird.

When the upgrade completed, I got a pop-up asking me how I wanted to handle the opening of webcal/ical links, and I (without paying attention) selected iCal and chose the "Always use this..." option.

Now iCal opens every 10 minutes or so and asks me what to do with the links, which is extremely annoying. I tried just adding those calendars to iCal and hoping it wouldn't open anymore, but to no avail.

I know I can change the default application on files by right clicking, but as far as I know I can't save a webcal link as a file that can be right clicked.

I'm thinking I need access to some preference list. I don't know where to look for this, and all of my searches take me to the, "Right click, Get Info, change the application it opens with" answer. I'm comfortable in Terminal, but I'm not sure where to start looking.

Has anyone seen this before? Any known solutions?

Note: I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). Download it, and install the Preference Pane by double-clicking the `.prefpane` file.

Then, go to *URLs → webcal* and select the application you want.

[image]

---

If the above doesn't work (for whatever reason):

You might also be able to remove the entry from the Launch Services associations. It's basically the same as what the app above does. The relevant entries are in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`. You can open this file with some editor like [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) or the Preference List Editor shipped with Xcode.

What I could find was something like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
    <string>com.apple.ical</string>
    <key>LSHandlerURLScheme</key>
    <string>webcal</string>
</dict>
```

You could try to delete it, save the file and [rebuild](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/06/11/terminal-tips-rebuild-your-launch-services-database-to-clean-up/) the launch services database.

Comment: Awesome! RCDefaultApp was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Changes to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` can also be applied by restarting the OS (logging out and back in isn't enough). Rebuilding the Launch Services database has some annoying side-effects like making Finder forget applications associated with file types.